# Logs on Google App Engine / Google Cloud Run are appearing incorrectly

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-run

I am looking to log messages with multiple lines separated by `\n` hence a log message can contain multiple lines in respect to the `\n` as shown in the screenshot below.

The `\n` is parsed as a new line which is correct but our problem is that it’s keeping it in the log output.
Note that we are using the default Java logger of the `java.util.logging package.`

This is the code snippet concerning the text we are looking to log:

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    logger.info("Log => " + prepareWelcomeMessage());
}


private static String prepareWelcomeMessage() {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    stringBuilder.append("\n ****************************** WELCOME ****************************** \n");
    stringBuilder.append(" ****************************** TO ****************************** \n");
    stringBuilder.append(" ****************************** THE ****************************** \n");
    stringBuilder.append(" ****************************** DEMO APPLICATION ****************************** \n");
    stringBuilder.append(" ****************************** TO VALIDATE ****************************** \n");
    stringBuilder.append(" ****************************** LOGS ****************************** \n");
    stringBuilder.append(" ****************************** ON APP ENGINE FLEX ****************************** \n");

    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

The expected result is:
[image]

The actual result is :
[image]

Comment: These are log are in json objects which is getting printed. How json will interpret \n? \n will only work if you print them in the console. You have to get the actual value from log object and print them..

Comment: I can't reproduce this. It works as you have in the expected case. Do you have any configuration for the logger?